# iOS10 NSLog is limited to 1024 chars strings

Tags: ios, console, ios10, xcode8

In iOS10 the NSlog are limited to 1024 characters has anybody know a workaround to print complete string.

Comment: split string into 1024 char chunks and log each one individually.

Comment: solution is good, but its seems to be hard to implement, as we use lot of logs. Especially the server response are huge and it would be good to log JSON without line breaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `printf` then instead of `NSLog` like,

```
   printf("%s", [string UTF8String]);
```

It may works

Comment: NSString *logMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<copy the old message>"];
printf("%s",[logMessage UTF8String]);

Answer (score 4):

I thinks this is a same question with [ [NSLog on devices in iOS 10 / Xcode 8 seems to truncate? Why？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584707/nslog-on-devices-in-ios-10-xcode-8-seems-to-truncate-why]), I will also post my answer here, in case you want to use `printf` instead.

This is a temporary solution,since I think it's a bug.

Just redefine all `NSLOG` to `printf` in a global header file.

```
#define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 3):

a Swift workaround for this new Xcode8 and Sierra “feature”…

```
func Log(_ format:String, _ args:CVarArg...) {
    let output = withVaList(args, { (p) -> NSString in
        NSString(format: format, arguments: p)
    }) as String
    print( output )
}
```

Of course, this won’t have the features of NSLog that we may require such as the time stamp, bundle name, and thread stuff (including serialization).