# Convert NSData to NSString - NSLog limitation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, curl, zendesk

I'm trying to convert `NSData` to `NSString` in Zendesk but am getting a incomplete string, or at least not able to fully decode the `data`.

When I `curl` the following command:

```
curl https://mySubdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/1038194884/tickets/requested.json   -v -u myLogin:myPassword
```

I get the correct response and it list all the tickets of this user, the response is as follows:

> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK  < Server: nginx  < Date: Sat, 28 Jan 2017 19:50:16
>   GMT  < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8  <
>   Content-Length: 12576  < Connection: keep-alive  <
>   X-Zendesk-API-Version: v2  < X-Zendesk-Application-Version: v8.28  <
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN  < X-Rate-Limit: 400  <
>   X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 399  < Strict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=31536000;  < X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1  < ETag:
>   "98b10cfcb2f1577122a1662926f9565c"  < Cache-Control: must-revalidate,
>   private, max-age=0  < X-Zendesk-Origin-Server:
>   app2.pod7.fra1.zdsys.com  < X-Request-Id:
>   db8b90fd-e3a3-452d-c5ea-ecf4bbd76e89  < X-Runtime: 0.303978  <
>   X-Rack-Cache: miss  < X-Zendesk-Request-Id: bdfd524aa5520cf39e57  <
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

When I try to to the same thing in `objective-C`, from `iOS` app, the response is pretty much the same, as follows:

> "Cache-Control" = "must-revalidate, private, max-age=0";
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Sat, 28 Jan 2017 20:36:38 GMT";
>       Etag = "\"98b10cfcb2f1577122a1662926f9565c\"";
>       Server = nginx;
>       "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000;";
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
>       "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
>       "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
>       "X-Rack-Cache" = miss;
>       "X-Rate-Limit" = 400;
>       "X-Rate-Limit-Remaining" = 399;
>       "X-Request-Id" = "53c1b462-2dec-4c46-cc60-ecf4bbd76e89";
>       "X-Runtime" = "0.209525";
>       "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
>       "X-Zendesk-API-Version" = v2;
>       "X-Zendesk-Application-Version" = "v8.28";
>       "X-Zendesk-Origin-Server" = "app4.pod7.fra1.zdsys.com";
>       "X-Zendesk-Request-Id" = 675ae5b4ff78fbe7

The problem is that wen I try to convert the `data` to a `dictionary` or `NSString`, I get incomplete `string`. This is the code I'm using:

```
NSString *urlUser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mySubdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/1038194884/tickets/requested.json"];
    NSURL *url  = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlUser];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request addValue : @"application/json"
   forHTTPHeaderField : @"Content-Type" ];

    NSString *authStr = @"username:password";
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@",[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession  sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"finished");
                                      if (!error)
                                      {

                                          NSLog(@"%@", data);
                                          NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", response);

                                          NSLog(@"length: %lu", data.length);

                                          //Determine if string is null-terminated
                                          char lastByte;
                                          [data getBytes:&lastByte range:NSMakeRange([data length]-1, 1)];

                                          NSString *str;

                                          if (lastByte == 0x0) {
                                              //string is null-terminated
                                              str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
                                          } else {
                                              //string is not null-terminated
                                              str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                          }

                                          NSLog(@"string length: %lu", str.length);

                                          NSLog(@"%@", str);

                                          NSLog(@"stop");




                                      }

                                  }];
    [task resume];
```

BTW, the `data` length is the same as in `curl` response.

logged string:

> {"tickets":[{"url":"https://mySubdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/407.json","id":407,"external_id":null,"via":{"channel":"mobile_sdk","source":{"from":{},"to":{},"rel":"mobile_sdk"}},"created_at":"2017-01-26T10:48:28Z","updated_at":"2017-01-26T11:05:42Z","type":null,"subject":"Comentário
>   sobre exercício.","raw_subject":"Comentário sobre
>   exercício.","description":"Nome do usuário: bruna villete\nObjectId:
>   qHQzNbjUzy\nPlano: Iron Training - brazil\n\nDETALHES DO EXERCÍCIO:
>   \nTitulo: CADEIRA EXTENSORA\nObjectId: qvq5deXxD9\nPerfil: MULHER
>   INICIANTE\nFrequência: 5\nPeríodo: Semana1\nSérie: Serie
>   B\n\nCOMENTÁRIO:
>   \nbom","priority":null,"status":"solved","recipient":null,"requester_id":1038194884,"submitter_id":1038194884,"assignee_id":3030446965,"organization_id":null,"group_id":24989965,"collaborator_ids":[],"forum_topic_id":null,"problem_id":null,"has_incidents":false,"is_public":true,"due_at":null,"tags":["seriecomment"],"custom_fields":[],"satisfaction_rating":null,"sharing_agreement_

Comment: what exactly means *incomplete string*?

Comment: it means it stops in the middle of the first ticket...where this specific user has several tickets as shown and returned in curl. Please see edited question for string. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that it's not just the `NSLog` call that is limited to a specific amount of characters?

Comment: Well, no. I'm not sure. How would I check that?

Comment: instead of using `NSLog` you could temporarily add a `UITextView` to your view and set its `text` property to your string...

Comment: you could also try to log it that way: `printf("%s", str.UTF8String);` - that way the output should not get cut off.

Comment: Perfect, that was the problem... I still need to work with the data, not sure if I'll have some characters problems... for now, your solution is great. Please write an answer.

Comment: @Jorge Latest Xcode has some issues regarding NSLog and dictionarys. This has been mentioned and asked about several threads. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412917/xcode-8-does-not-display-the-whole-nslog-output , for the NSData part, I answered how to solve your issue, you need to serialize the response into a dictionary. If the answer solves your issue, please accept it as correct :) GL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON serialized data to NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603047/how-to-convert-json-serialized-data-to-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I told you in the comments it looks like the `NSLog` statement cuts off the string. everything works as expected.

to work with your data, convert it to a json object and use it like this:

```
// convert the response data to json
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"json parsing succeeded.");
}

// access your data
NSArray *tickets = json[@"tickets"];
```

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?

Comment: it includes the json parsing. and since i answered the thread's question in the comments above i created an answer (as @Jorge asked me to).

Comment: Your comments was about the NSLog part, your solution in your answer however for the serialization was a copy of my answer. And you don't need a textview everytime you want to run an NSLog on something, you can iterate through every key and log out the values instead in the console. However I won't downvote your answer, but next time don't copy other peoples answers when it has already been answered.

Comment: well... if you feel like i copied your answer feel free to downvote it. the thread is about "getting an incomplete string" and thats exactly what i explained in my comments - thus it is the answer! the json and data accessing part is just an extra. i'm out :)

Comment: My answer was posted 10 minutes before yours. Thats not a feeling thats a fact. Your "comment" was only regarding the NSLog , and you suggest the user to create a UITextView everytime he wants to log a text from a dictionary. Really awesome tips.Your answer here however, was a copy of mine and not a single mention about it in the comments you made.

Answer (score 1):

[First convert the JSON response to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603047/how-to-convert-json-serialized-data-to-nsdictionary)

Then access your NSString from the dictionary as usual. (Or any other value/key in your JSON Response)

```
NSString *myStr = [json objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```